# Charater ê getting replaced with &ecirc, How to correct in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, internationalization, cdata

I am displaying a Java Script alert message read from an XML. XML is UTF-8 encoded.

Characters like `ê` `ç` `ã` `í` are getting replaced while displaying the Alert message , like `ê` getting replaced with `&ecirc` and so on. I have tried CDATA casting but not resolved.

This is part of an i8ln project , please let me know how can this be corrected.

Thanks

Comment: this might be crazy, but ... making your site UTF-8 encoded? it's pretty much a web standard for the last decade.

Comment: Where do these characters get replaced?

Comment: @Remy these characters are getting replaced while message is displaying on the Popup. Você - Voc&ecirc , çã - &ccidl;&atilde;

Comment: Java Script Alert Popup

Comment: I'm hard-pressed to believe that. Are you sure? Did you debug it?

Comment: Yes. If I am providing the message Directly within the JavaScript Function as a String as is then the characters are getting displayed as expected. We face the issue when we are asking the JavaScript function to read from XML.